# MySQL Procedure Find: How to SELECT one specific named column FROM different tables

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I want to write a PROCEDURE to find and fill the ID searching through many tables.
Consider this: A city has three different bus companies with different routes at different times. For me as a customer I don't mind which one I go with as long as my preferences in time are fulfilled. I want to search through all three companies in one query to find the one matching my wish the best.

This is what I've tried:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE book_fixed_route(
    IN pnr VARCHAR(100),
    IN source INT(11),
    IN dest INT(11),
    IN start_time TIME,
    IN frequency CHAR(7),
    IN start_date DATE,
    IN end_date DATE)
INSERT INTO booking
     VALUES (pnr,
                 (SELECT ID
                    FROM route r, company2.route j , company3.route m
                   WHERE (r.source = source AND r.starttime = start_time)
                      OR (j.source = source AND j.starttime = start_time)
                      OR (m.source = source AND m.starttime = start_time)),
                 (SELECT vehicleID
                    FROM route r, company2.route j , company3.route m
                   WHERE (r.source = source AND r.starttime = start_time)
                      OR (j.source = source AND j.starttime = start_time)
                      OR (m.source = source AND m.starttime = start_time)));
```

Where all the companies' route-tables look exactly the same and the booking table to which I write takes pnr, route_id and vehicle_id.

The above code gives me error code 1052 and I THINK it it because I don't specify which company it should choose the ID or vehicleID (after SELECT).

I am truly thankful for all the help I can get!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1052 is going to arise from mysql not being able to tell which table (route, company2.route or company3.route) ID is supposed to come from.  I don't think mysql supports specifying a table as company2.route (several other RDBMs do, though they differ in what it means.)

Putting each company's data in a separate table is not good design.  You should have a single route table with a company_id column that references a separate company table with the particulars for that company.  That wil simplify your problem into a reasonable statement.